# Flutter Json Call

Tags: json, flutter, dart

My everythink ready

```
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return (jsonDecode(response.body)).map((sendData){
      return Restaurant.fromJson(sendData);
    }).toList();
  } else {
    throw Exception('data error');
  }
```

my json

{
"id": 2,
"restaurant_name": "Eethuis Orient Dev",
"restaurant_slug": "eethuis-orient-heusden",.............
....
}

I think problem is my return use

```
return (jsonDecode(response.body) as List).map((sendData){
      return Restaurant.fromJson(sendData);
```

thank you

Comment: Your json is starting with curly braces "{" or square brackets "[" ?

Comment: aslında onu gostermek ıcın yazmıstım ama "{" bunun ıcınde

Comment: Reply in English please.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is not a list. So `jsonDecode(response.body) as List` will not be successful.

Either change your JSON or change your code, I cannot tell you which of those are wrong.

---

Well, your edit removed the `as List` part and then continues to treat your data as a list. If you truly expect only one element, this will be the code that you need:

```
return Restaurant.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
```

Comment: thank you I chance but still dont working :/

Comment: https://dev.etenonline.be/xHttp/subweb?id=2%26token%3Ddeneme benim json this and need list :/ ı need more element

Comment: You use https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/# for validate the json. 
And this json it's valid. I tried to valid with positive esit.

Comment: Wel, I don't know what you want me to say, your json is *exactly one* restaurant. I cannot magically make a list from it. It's just one.

Comment: You are quite right. really my fault :(